# Does Aeon have a web wallet?

Tags: aeon, web-wallet

Does Aeon have a web wallet, similar to [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Aeon web wallet [AEON Pocket](https://aeonpocket.com/) was recently [announced](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/7qceqa/aeon_pocket_secure_web_wallet_for_aeon/) on Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

Stay clear of Aeon Pocket. you can receive but you cannot send more than 0.1 and even that fails often. it appears like a scam since wont allow you to send. I would stay very clear of it.